# Why Google Ads not linked to Google Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-ads-api

I have Google Analytics App and Web Account. It automatically created with Firebase.

i have linked my google ads account to my analytics account. it has shown on my google analytics account that my ads account is now linked. but on my google ads account, it still does not show any connection to google analytics.

I have a get this error "The Google Account that you're using doesn't have 'Edit' permission to any Analytics properties. To link accounts, or make changes to your link, ask the administrator of the Analytics account for 'Edit' permission. " in the Google ads. But all permissions granted.

What should i do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The linking of Google Ads and Google Analytics is unidirectional no bidirectional. You have to go into Google Ads and link that with the corresponding Google Analytics account. You also have to go into Google Analytics and link that with the corresponding Google Ads account. For permissions, try going into Google Marketing Platform and into the integration center. Here you will see the unidirectional nature and a page for Google Analytics links and Google Ads links.